# How can I stop tinymce from adding <!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body> to everything I enter?

Tags: php, javascript, html, tinymce

I am using TinyMCE as the editor for a field in my database. When I use it and add the text "abc" then this is what gets stored in the database:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body><p>abc</p></body></html>
```

How can I stop TinyMCE from adding everything around the `<p>` tags?

Comment: This may help, seems to agree with @liyakay `http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=19169`

Answer (score 46, accepted):

maybe this can help , it's when i have add the plugin : `fullpage` , add the properties `button`

or hold of a plugin called `FullPage.js` for TinyMCE.

hope this will help you.

Answer (score 6):

remove fullpage from plugin
 plugins: [
                "advlist autolink autosave link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak spellchecker",
                "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking",
                "table contextmenu directionality emoticons template textcolor paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern"
        ],